# HTML/CSS lists column sorting

Tags: html, css, sorting, html-lists

i have a little problem in sorting LI tags when i'm using *column* function.
By default it is sorting normally but i had to use columns in CSS and after that my list is like this:

1 - 6
2 - 7
3 - 8
4 - 9
5 - 10

but i need something like this:

1 - 2
3 - 4
5 - 6
7 - 8
9 - 10

here is my code: [jsfiddle](http://bit.ly/1gX6fzf)

Comment: would you like to do this in table ?

Comment: nope :( unfortunately i can't use table in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JSFiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/NB2sk/11/)

**CSS**

```
.grid_1, .grid_2 {
    margin-left : 1.00%;
    margin-right : 1.00%;
    margin-bottom : 15px !important;
    float : left;
    display : block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.grid_1 {
    width: 98%;
}
.grid_2 {
    width: 48%;
}
.bg {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grid_1 ">
    <div class="grid_2">
        <div class="grid_1 bg">1</div>
        <div class="grid_1 bg">3<br> dgdgdfgdfg<br> sdrfsdrfrter</div>
        <div class="grid_1 bg">5</div>
        <div class="grid_1 bg">7</div>
        <div class="grid_1 bg">9</div>
        <div class="grid_1 bg">11</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_2">
        <div class="grid_1 bg">2</div>
        <div class="grid_1 bg">4</div>
        <div class="grid_1 bg">6</div>
        <div class="grid_1 bg">8</div>
        <div class="grid_1 bg">10</div>
        <div class="grid_1 bg">12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes but there is the same problem now between 3 and 7 and between 9 and 12, it must be dynamic layout too

Comment: can u use <div> instead of unordered list?

Comment: unfortunately i can use only one grid

Comment: everything other is perfect

Answer (score 1):

I found the way at [Multiple column lists using one ul](http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/).

I try to use it. Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g3z2H/2/)**

Demo code below :

```
ul {
  clear: both;
  width:450px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

li {
  line-height:1.5em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

#double li { 
  width:40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to this  add `float:left` and define `box-sizing:border-box;` as like this

```
   ul {
        clear: both;
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding: 10px 0px 0 0px;
        width: 450px;
        z-index: 9; }

    ul li {
        background:#ededed;
        float:left;
    min-height:100px;
    width:50%;
-webikit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
        list-style: none;         
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 0px;

        }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/g3z2H/5/)**

Comment: Every li had different height so if i delete min-height in your script it would be like so: [jsfiddle](http://bit.ly/1e7mpQK) :(

Comment: @user3484379 I think `min-height` should be added to get the best appearance, otherwise your problem can be hardly solved, I don't understand why you want to remove min-height.

Comment: in my design i should have dynamically heights, so for nice appearance  it must have different heights

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code **[Updated URL](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/g3z2H/38/)**

```
    ul {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 0 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    z-index: 9;
    display: block;
}
ul li {
    background:#ededed;
    text-align:left;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 1% 0 0;
    padding: 0px;
    width:49%;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: yeah i tried same way too but there lefts space between 3/three and 6 - and between 8 and 10, because neighbour columns have different height

Comment: there is again spage but now between 4 and 6.. and if i append some rows see how it will look: [jsfiddle](bit.ly/1mHjZAg) but i need that every li was under the upper